# I have imported the data in R, how to make a scatter plot?

Tags: r

I'm new to `R`, and have imported my dataset as follows (dots mean that there is remaining data):

```
> num.csv <- read.csv("c:/num.csv", header=T)
> print(num.csv)
            X.Y
1     22500;482
2       25842;1
3       27221;1
4       32757;1
5       40152;1
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

How can I make a scatter plot for this data?

Thanks.

Comment: No need for `print(...)` if you are working with R interactively. Autoprinting means that when you enter the name of an object and hit return, R invokes `print()` for you.

Comment: That clearly hasn't worked; you have a single column of data in R now, with column name `X.Y` and data from the original 2 columns in your CSV file concatenated. Is your file actually **comma** separated. Looks like it is separated by `;`, which suggests you are using a computer in a foreign locale where you use `,` as the decimal place. If so, use `read.csv2()` instead. If that is the case, morale of the story is to check your data have been read in correctly. Use `str(foo)` and `ncol(foo)`, `nrow(foo)` etc. where `foo` is the object containing your data.

Comment: @Gavin: or use `sep=";"`

Comment: @nico not if the decimal place is also `,`. Then you have to use `dec = ","` too. Easier to use `read.csv2()` - that's what it was created for.

Comment: @Gavin: I don't really find it easier, as I never remember which one is which. I prefer to use `read.table` and set `sep` depending on my need at the time. PS: comma for decimal places... don't let me started on that ;)

Comment: @nico I agree, but if you do have a CSV file then they are reasonably well defined hence the the two read.csv() functions. Whomsoever decided on using `,` for the decimal needs to take a good long look at themselves ;-)

Answer (score 8):

First, the data needs to be in separate columns.  While the file is labeled "csv", you appear to be using semicolons to separate instead of commas.  Either reformat the file or try:

```
num.csv <- read.csv("c:/num.csv", header=T, sep=";")
```

Then you can use one of the various plotting packages with R to make a plot.  For example:

```
install.packages("ggplot2"); #ggplot2 is not part of the standard install...
library(ggplot2);
qplot(X, Y, data=num.csv);
```

I have not tested the above, it depends on how your data frame comes out of read.csv.

Comment: Or, one can just use R basic `plot` function: `plot(X, Y, data=num.csv)`.

Answer (score 4):

@patrickmdmnet's answer is the way to go but I got a little curious and just wanted to try a programmatic solution. I was mostly curious of how the R strplit() funciton worked:

```
# Test matrix
tmp.mtrx <- matrix(c("1;2", "3;4", "5;6", "7;8"), ncol=1)

# The split
tmp.split <- strsplit(tmp.mtrx, ";")

# Put it all together into a new matrix
new_matrix <- matrix(tmp.split[[1]], ncol=2)
for(i in 2:length(tmp.split)){
  new_matrix <- rbind(new_matrix, tmp.split[[i]])
}

# Do the plot originally asked for
plot(new_matrix[,1], new_matrix[,2])
```

@ Chl - I was looking for the unlist function, it makes the solution nicer without the loop although since I've been programming a lot I often find it nicer to have my code more readable if it doesn't have a too large affect on performance. Here's Chl's solution in a with a slightly more complex matrix:

```
# Test matrix
tmp.mtrx <- matrix(c("1;2", 55,  "3;4", 75, "5;6", 85, "7;8", 88), ncol=2)

# The split
tmp.split <- strsplit(tmp.mtrx, ";")

# A vector with all the values, length = (ncol(tmp.mtrx) + 1)*nrow(tmp.mtrx)
tmp.data_vector <- unlist(tmp.split)

# Put it all together into a new matrix
new_matrix <- matrix(tmp.data_vector, ncol=(ncol(tmp.mtrx)+1), byrow=TRUE)

# Do the plot originally asked for
plot(new_matrix[,1], new_matrix[,2])
```

Comment: You can safely replace the 3rd block by `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(tmp_split)), nc=2, byrow=TRUE)`. Also, `plot` works well with a 2-column matrix, so the last statement might be replaced with `plot(new_matrix)`.